# Why doesn't round() work as expected on exponential numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding, exponential

Formatting the number works and cut unwanted decimals. Is there a reason the `round()` function give the same value passed by parameter?

```
number = 5.7821323121209e19
print(round(number,2)) # 5.7821323121209e19.
# Works.
print('%.3g' % number) # 5.78e19
print('{:.3g}'.format(number))  # 5.78e19
print(f'{number:.3g}')   # 5.78e19
```

Comment: "Doesn't work"? What does it give you, and what did you expect?

Comment: Edit the question to explain "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works correctly. `5.7821323121209e19` is actually `5.7821323121209 * (10 ** 19)` so it is a number with only **0** after the comma.

Therefore there is nothing to round from mathematical point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want `-17` instead of `2`:

```
>>> round(5.7821323121208e19, -17)
5.78e+19
```

Answer (score 1):

[`round(number, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) rounds to 2 decimal places (i.e. hundredths). `5.7821323121209e19` is much too big for that to have any effect. It is `57821323121209000000`.